# What's the point of tornado.locale.Locale.translate?

Tags: python, web, tornado

Documentation: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/locale.html?highlight=translate#tornado.locale.Locale.translate

I saw an submit button in some html file: `<input type="submit" value="{{ _("Post") }}"/>` and confused at why the author set `value={{ _("Post") }}` instead of just `value="Post"`. What's the point of the translation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tornado templates `_` is just an established way to call `translate` method of configured  locale and it is globally available in any template (see [Tornado's templates translate function '_', where does it come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567969)).

[tornado.locale.Locale.translate](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/locale.py#L265) is an abstract method and throws `NotImplentedError` if called dirrectly. It is implemented in [GettextLocale](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/locale.py#L442) or [CSVLocale](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/locale.py#L414) classes.